# How do I test if there is a server open on a port with python?

Tags: python, sockets, windows-xp, python-2.5

I did the following, figuring it would raise an exception if it could not connect:

```
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> s.settimeout(0.2)
>>> s.connect(("thisdomaiyndontexistduhh.com", 80))
```

But no exception was raised.

How do I test if there is a server open on a port with Python's socket module?

Comment: Of course you will see an exception....either an error for a failed DNS lookup or e.g. a timeout error if you can't connect.

Comment: I get `socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname`.

Comment: Maybe I should check my code. I guess it's possible I imported something that overrode sys.stderr...

Comment: Well, I found it only works when I connect to a url without a /file.fileextention after the main domain name.

Comment: Just checked, my sys.stderr is normal. This is very odd.

Comment: I am using Python 2.5 if that makes any difference...

Comment: Does `socket.gethostbyname_ex('thisdomaindoesnotexist.com')` fails or not?

Comment: Bad example. That domain actually DOES exist. You can open it in a web browser. But it does NOT fail for http://thisdomaindoesnotexist.com.co/ which actually doesn't exist.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357431/how-do-i-use-python-socket-library-to-check-if-a-remote-port-is-open

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's why the code above never fails.

My ISP (Frontier) configures DNS such that for any domain that does not exist, it will return "198.105.251.114".  As such, they actually have a web server listening on port 80 at that address to display some garbage/spam search results.  Change your host to use 8.8.8.8 (Google server) for DNS and your code above will likely work.

Given that these sorts of "captive networks" are common, the first thing your code should do is determine if it is on such a network.  Hence, the right thing to do is call socket.gethostbyname("thisdomaiyndontexistduhh.com").  If it actually returns a value, then you know you are behind such a DNS server.  As such, then do a gethostbyname call on the server you want to probe.  If it returns the same DNS address, you know the server doesn't exist.  Otherwise, proceed with the connect call to finish the test.

Update: I've been learning Python over the  holidays, so I used this problem as excuse to practice. Here's my code:

```
import socket

def DoesServiceExist(host, port):
    captive_dns_addr = ""
    host_addr = ""

    try:
        captive_dns_addr = socket.gethostbyname("BlahThisDomaynDontExist22.com")
    except:
        pass

    try:
        host_addr = socket.gethostbyname(host)

        if (captive_dns_addr == host_addr):
            return False

        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.settimeout(1)
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.close()
    except:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: This returns true for ports that are not open! This only validates the host, not the port.

Comment: @JonathanLeaders - I don't think what you have stated is correct. The `s.connect((host,port))` call will fail and throw an exception if there is no listener at the specified `port` on that `host`. However, it *does not* validate that the service or expected protocol at that port actually is running - it just validates that the host has an active listener that's accepting connections (on that port). Perhaps you can cite an example of a case that erroneously returns True, when it should return False. I can clear up the confusion as needed.

Comment: I just ran a for loop and connected to my server on over 9,000 ports. There's only a few ports open. This can't be correct. I apologize for the formatting, but this was basically what I did:
`import socket
 for p in range(9999):
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      s.connect(('google.com', p+1))`

Try different servers. Maybe it's a windows thing?

Comment: I get a TimeoutError exceptionon `s.connect` as expected when I try to `s.connect` to any port on google.com that isn't 443 or 80 (as expected). Get a Netmon or Wireshark trace to see what's going on under the hood.  My hypothetical guess is that you are on some sort of work\enterprise network that has a proxy or firewall in the middle.  Or your NAT is just doing something non-standard.  Or you are on a captive network.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution using `telnetlib` and `urllib` to test the connection between servers in urls like "https://example.com:6789/test", in this particular case, I'm looking for the port first, then the schema. I'm considering just "http" and "https" but it's easy to add or change the schema (sftp, ssh, etc.).

```
import telnetlib
import time
from urllib.parse import urlsplit

def verify_service(endpoint):

    netloc = "{0.netloc}".format(urlsplit(endpoint))
    scheme = "{0.scheme}".format(urlsplit(endpoint))

    if netloc == '':
        return False

    p = netloc.split(":")

    if len(p) == 2:
        host = p[0]
        port = p[1]
    else:
        host = p[0]
        port = 80 if scheme == "http" else "443"

    try:
        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host,port)
        time.sleep(1)
    except:
        return False

    return True
```